# Validar si hay un checkbox seleccionado AngularJS

Tags: html5, angularjs

Buenas, tengo un problema que no sé como hacer. Tengo un formulario con una lista de checkbox y tengo que validar que haya por lo menos uno seleccionado.

el formulario es este:

```
<form id="formDetails" name="formDetails" ng-submit="sendForm()">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic">Children's</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic">Health & Beauty</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic">Science & Nature</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic">Crafts & Hobbies</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic">History</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic">Sports & Fitness</label>
        </div>
        <span class="error" ng-show="formDetails.topic.$error.required">Please select at least one topic</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Si no hay ninguno seleccionado, debería aparecer el mensaje y si por lo menos hay 1 checkbox seleccionado, debería ocultarse el mensaje.

Cómo podría hacer la función para validar si hay uno seleccionado? Sé como validar el checkbox de uno en uno, pero no de esta forma.

muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar jquery plano sin necesidad de utilizar angular. Solo buscas los checkbox que estan `checked`:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.error = false; 
  
  $scope.sendForm = function()
  {
    if($("#formDetails input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 0) {
     alert("enviar form");
$scope.error = true; 
     }
     else{
       alert("no enviar form");
$scope.error = false; 
     }
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" id="formDetails" name="formDetails" ng-submit="sendForm()">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic">Children's</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic">Health & Beauty</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic">Science & Nature</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic">Crafts & Hobbies</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic">History</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-info">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="topic">Sports & Fitness</label>
        </div>
        <span class="error" ng-show="error">Please select at least one topic</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: y el mensaje de error que tengo que mostrar `<span class="error" ng-show="formDetails.topic.$error.required">Please select at least one topic</span>` como lo muestro si no hay nada seleccionado y lo oculto si se selecciona 1 checkbox?

Comment: `formDetails.topic.$error.required` es una propiedad de tu modelo?

Comment: he puesto ese span de mensaje con el `ng-show` como tengo la validación del checkbox de la politica de privacidad y ahi me sale el mensaje pero en la lista de checkbox tengo que mostrar ese mensaje, el cual no sé como mostrarlo, cuando tengo esa lista de checkbox y ninguno está seleccionado

Comment: Dale una mirada a la respuesta actualizada y dime si eso es lo que esperaba.

Comment: si, era eso. Muchas gracias

Comment: tengo otro problema con la validación de los checkbox, que con la función que me dijiste, es para validar todos los checkbox del formulario y claro, ahora que he agregado otros 2 checkbox distintos a la lista que puse, uno para la politica de privacidad y para si es mayor de edad, si selecciono 1 cualquiera ya me valida todos los checkbox, he modificado `input[type=checkbox]` poniendo el id y he creado 3 if distintos, uno por cada id pero no me funciona correctamente, como podría hacerlo? o abro otra pregunta?